# Libgdx detect when player is outside of screen

Tags: collision-detection, libgdx, sprites, viewport

Im trying to learn libGDX (coming from XNA/MonoDevelop), and I'm making a super simple test game to get to know it better. I was wondering how to detect if the player sprite is outside of the screen and make it so it is impossible to go outside of the screen edges.

In XNA you could do something like this:

```
// Prevent player from moving off the left edge of the screen
if (player.Position.X < 0)
    player.Position = new Vector2(0, player.Position.Y);
```

How is this achieved in libgdx? I think it's the Stage that handles the 2D viewport in libgdx?

This is my code so far:

```
private Texture texture;
private SpriteBatch batch;
private Sprite sprite;

@Override
public void create () {
    float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("player.png"));
    sprite = new Sprite(texture);
    sprite.setPosition(w/2 -sprite.getWidth()/2, h/2 - sprite.getHeight()/2);
}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT)){
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.CONTROL_LEFT))
            sprite.translateX(-1f);
        else
            sprite.translateX(-10.0f);
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT)){
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.CONTROL_LEFT))
            sprite.translateX(1f);
        else
            sprite.translateX(10f);
    }

    batch.begin();
    sprite.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most surefire way to do this is to test each frame if the sprite has exceeded the desired boundaries (either physical screen or camera viewport), and if so to clamp them back to the exact boundary.  This will prevent any weird bouncing effects from trying to correct the position using an offset, and enable the sprite to collide snugly with the boundaries.

I also come from an XNA background so I made changes along with the code to hopefully make the structure more familiar to you.  Anyway, modifying your existing code:

```
private static final float SPEED = 10f; // 10 pixels per second
private static final float SPEED_SLOW = 1f; // 1 pixel per second

private Texture texture;
private SpriteBatch batch;
private Sprite sprite;

@Override
public void create () {
    float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("player.png"));
    sprite = new Sprite(texture);
    //sprite.setPosition(w/2 -sprite.getWidth()/2, h/2 - sprite.getHeight()/2);

    // Set the origin of the sprite (where its position is relative to) to the center of the sprite.
    // The default origin is the bottom-left corner which is why you were making the adjustment above 
    // to make it appear centered.  This also allows the sprite to rotate around its center, scale around
    // its center, etc.
    sprite.setOriginCenter();
    sprite.setPosition(w * .5f, h * .5f);
}

@Override
public void render () {
    final float dt = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

    update(dt);
    draw();
}

private void update(final float dt)
{
    // Get input for this frame
    final boolean left = Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT);
    final boolean right = Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT);
    final boolean up = Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP);
    final boolean down  = Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN);
    final boolean slow = Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.CONTROL_LEFT);

    // Calculate directional speed
    float speedX = slow ? SPEED_SLOW : SPEED;
    speedX *= (left ? -1f : right ? 1f : 0f);
    // Scale by our delta time for smooth movement.  Optional
    speedX *= dt;

    float speedY = slow ? SPEED_SLOW : SPEED;
    speedY *= (down ? -1f : up ? 1f : 0f);
    // Scale by our delta time for smooth movement.  Optional
    speedY *= dt;

    // Move sprite to new position
    sprite.translate(speedX, speedY);

    // Get the bounding rectangle that describes the boundary of our sprite based on position, size, and scale.
    final Rectangle bounds = sprite.getBoundingRectangle();

    // Get the bounding rectangle that our screen.  If using a camera you would create this based on the camera's
    // position and viewport width/height instead.
    final Rectangle screenBounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

    // Sprite
    float left = bounds.getX();
    float bottom = bounds.getY();
    float top = bottom + bounds.getHeight();
    float right = left + bounds.getWidth();

    // Used for adjustments below since our origin is now the center.
    final float halfWidth = bounds.getWidth() * .5f; 
    final float halfHeight = bounds.getHeight() * .5f;

    // Screen
    float screenLeft = screenBounds.getX();
    float screenBottom = screenBounds.getY();
    float screenTop = screenBottom + screenBounds.getHeight();
    float screenRight = screenLeft + screenBounds.getWidth();

    // Current position
    float newX = sprite.getX();
    float newY = sprite.getY();

    // Correct horizontal axis
    if(left < screenLeft)
    {
        // Clamp to left
        newX = screenLeft + halfWidth;
    }
    else if(right > screenRight)
    {
        // Clamp to right
        newX = screenRight - halfWidth;
    }

    // Correct vertical axis
    if(bottom < screenBottom)
    {
        // Clamp to bottom
        newY = screenBottom + halfHeight;
    }
    else if(top > screenTop)
    {
        // Clamp to top
        newY = screenTop - halfHeight;
    }

    // Set sprite position.
    sprite.setPosition(newX, newY);
}

private void draw()
{
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);        

    batch.begin();
    sprite.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
}
```

Note this is written off the cuff and untested.  Take with a grain of salt and an eye for mistakes. :)

Comment: thank you! exactly what I needed to understand this :) I would also vote up your answer if I could :P

Comment: I would suggest to *not*  instantiate a `new Rectangle()` within update() - this would be done like 60 times per second. It would be better to create that rectangle once, since it never changes, and re-use it.

Answer (score -1):

```
add the following conditions:

        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT))
    {
            if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.CONTROL_LEFT) && sprite.getX() > 1f)
    {
                sprite.translateX(-1f);
    }
            elseif ( sprite.getX() > 10f)
    {

                sprite.translateX(-10.0f);
    }
}
```

this will prevent the user from getting outside of the screen 
tell me if you need an explain for the code above.

Comment: thank you! I understand the code above, just didn't think it would be that easy ;) . Is this the "normal" way to detect if the player is outside of the screen, or is it just a fix to my problem right now for this very simple game? I will test it out tomorrow when I have the time :)

Comment: no it's a good way to prevent the player from getting outside of the screen .

Comment: I would instead choose to see if the player has exceeded the boundary of the screen/viewport and then clamp them to the appropriate axis and boundary.  Think of how this example plays out if the sprite is at 15,20 and LEFT is pressed? You'll never reach the actual edge of the screen.

Comment: if (sprite.getX() < 10 && leftkeyispressed) then sprite.setposition(0,sprite.getY())

Comment: do you have any code example of what you mean @deadpixelsociety ?

Comment: I responded with a fully fleshed out answer.